# ¿como puedo compilar todos los archivos jade de una carpeta al mismo tiempo en windows?

Tags: nodejs, npm, jade

Tengo Windows 7 y quiero ejecutar el comando npm y compilar todos los archivos jade que están en la libreria lib, este es el comando que quiero usar:

```
jade --watch --pretty lib/*.jade --out .
```

y me genera el siguiente error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\4marzo\proyecto1\lib\*.jade'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:1003:11)
at renderFile (C:\Users\4marzo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jade\bin\jade.js:227:17)
at tryRender (C:\Users\4marzo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jade\bin\jade.js:181:5)
at C:\Users\4marzo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jade\bin\jade.js:136:5
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\4marzo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jade\bin\jade.js:135:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
```

NOTA: Esto funciona cuando pongo el nombre especifico de un archivo jade, por ejemplo:

```
jade --watch --pretty lib/index.jade --out .
```

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo mi propia pregunta:

Después de investigar a fondo en la documentación de Jade, encontré que este es el comando exacto para que se ejecute en Windows.

```
jade --watch --pretty lib --out .
```